# Cross join between two large datasets in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 large datasets. 
First dataset contains about 130 million entries.
The second dataset contains about 40000 entries. 
The data is fetched from MySQL tables.

I need to do a cross-join but I am getting

```
java.sql.SQLException: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

What is the best optimum technique to do this in Scala?

Following is a snippet of my code:

```
val df1 = (spark.read.jdbc(jdbcURL,configurationLoader.mysql_table1,"id",100,100000,40, MySqlConnection.getConnectionProperties))
val df2 = (spark.read.jdbc(jdbcURL,configurationLoader.mysql_table2, MySqlConnection.getConnectionProperties))
val df2Cache = df2.repartition(40).cache()
val crossProduct = df1.join(df2Cache)
```

df1 is the larger dataset and df2 is the smaller one.

Comment: pls add your code with examples which is producing the error. it will be very difficult to answer the questions with out seeing code and scenarios.

Comment: Consider if you really need to do a `crossJoin`. There is no optimum technique. Cartesian products are expensive.

Comment: Expect .52 trillion records

Comment: The number of records would be high no doubt. But how should the data partitioning be done ideally? I am quite new to Spark. I placed 40 as a number considering the fact that I have 10 executors and 4 cores for each executor.

Comment: need your spark-submit and full error stack trace

Answer (score 6):

130M*40K = 52 trillion records is 52 terabytes of required memory to store this data, and this is if we assume that each record is 1 byte, which is most certainly not true. If it is as much as 64 bytes (which I think is also a very conservative estimate), you'd need 3.32 petabytes (!) of memory just to store the data. It is a very large amount, so unless you have a very large cluster and very fast network inside that cluster, you might want to rethink your algorithm to make it work.

That being said, when you do a `join` of two SQL datasets/dataframes, the number of partitions that Spark would use to store the result of the join is controlled by the `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` property (see [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html#other-configuration-options)). You might want to set it to a very large number, and set the number of executors to the largest one that you can. Then you might be able to run your processing to the end.

Additionally, you may want to look into the [`spark.shuffle.minNumPartitionsToHighlyCompress`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/19e17acf2dbb058d17efcc3c01633c1583590af7/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/internal/config/package.scala#L676) option; if you set it to less than your number of shuffle partitions, you might get another memory boost. Note that this option was a hardcoded constant set to 2000 until a recent Spark version, so depending on your environment you just will need to set `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` to a number greater than 2000 to make use of it.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Vladimir, thought of adding more points.

see  [MapStatus](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/115fecfd840d58ce3211bf1dd7b130cb862730a5/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/MapStatus.scala#L59) set `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` it to `2001` ([old approach](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/4be33758354e1f95fd1d82a5482f3f00218e8c91/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/MapStatus.scala#L52-L58))(default is 200).

new approach (`spark.shuffle.minNumPartitionsToHighlyCompress`) as Vladimir mentioned in answer.

Why this change ? : ***[MapStatus has 2000 hardcoded SPARK-24519](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24519)***

it will apply different algorithm to process

```
def apply(loc: BlockManagerId, uncompressedSizes: Array[Long]): MapStatus = {
    if (uncompressedSizes.length > minPartitionsToUseHighlyCompressMapStatus) {
      HighlyCompressedMapStatus(loc, uncompressedSizes)
    } else {
      new CompressedMapStatus(loc, uncompressedSizes)
    }
  }
```

`HighlyCompressedMapStatus` :

> A MapStatus implementation that stores the accurate size of huge
>   blocks, which are larger than spark.shuffle.accurateBlockThreshold.
>   It stores the average size of other non-empty blocks,  plus a bitmap
>   for tracking which blocks are empty.

[spark.shuffle.accurateBlockThreshold](https://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-docs/latest/configuration.html#shuffle-behavior) - [see here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/19e17acf2dbb058d17efcc3c01633c1583590af7/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/internal/config/package.scala#L521) :     When we compress the size of shuffle blocks in `HighlyCompressedMapStatus`, we will record the size accurately if it's above this config. This helps to prevent OOM by avoiding underestimating shuffle block size when fetch shuffle blocks.

---

`CompressedMapStatus` :

> A MapStatus implementation that tracks the size of each block. Size
>   for each block is represented using a single byte.

Also set to your `spark-submit`

```
--conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=<10% of executor memory>  -- conf spark.shuffle.compress=true --conf spark.shuffle.spill.compress=true
```

in both cases Compression will use `spark.io.compression.codec`

> ***Conclusion*** : large tasks should use `HighlyCompressedMapStatus` and executor memory overhead can be 10 percent of your executor memory.

Further, have a look at [spark memory tuning](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#memory-tuning)

Answer (score 0):

Increase the SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY to higher value and repartition to more partitions